# Debugging tool in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging

Does anybody know if there is a third party debugging tool to debug SQL code in SQL server 2008 R2? Similar to the debugger in VS2010.

Comment: It might help if you list some requirements you have, such as ability to set break points, add watches, etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why Do You need debugger other than one included in SQL Server 2008R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the [TSQL debugger in SQL Server 2008 management studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646008.aspx). 
Also [here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=618LE_FZCxI) showing how to use it

Comment: Didn't know that SQl server 2008 had a debugging tool

Comment: Why does it need the user to be admin on the target database in order to debug SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz, however for the sake of options here you go.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/

it is a paid option, however I think you can get a demo that may allow you to get your debugging done for a bit.